# Can a paper be rejected for not using western blot?

Tags: peer-review

I'm going to be brief with this post. We have submitted a paper to journal x. We had two reviewers. Both had comments which we addressed in our response letter. Reviewer 1 endorsed the paper. However, reviewer 2 rejected it cause we did not use western blot to confirm the protein level of gene x. Is this normal? This same reviewer wanted us to repeat the whole experiment using a method they suggested. Morevover, this method, if applied, deviates from the goal of our work and is not suitable at all.
Finally, I should mention that our work focuses gene expression
Manipulation and possible  mechanisms involved.

I appreciate any feedback shedding lights on reviewers requesting additional work or differentvmethods that are not important to the work.

Comment: Not everyone here will know what "western blot" is. Is it fair to say that you did some work with one method, but your reviewer prefers a different method? Would most people in the field agree that one of the methods is superior?

Comment: You should get advice from a person who has read your paper.

Answer (score 6):

Your paper can be rejected if any of the reviewers are able to convince the editor that your paper is deficient in some way. That can include things that are in the paper that are done wrong, and things that are not in the paper that make the results questionable or open to other interpretations not fully explored.

If a reviewer requests experiments that do not fit the goals of the paper, and you are not willing or not able to do the experiments, it's up to you to make the best case for it in your response to the reviewers (which is also for the editor) while also being polite and respectful of their concerns. Even if their proposed solution does not seem to make sense to you, you can propose alternative methods/explanations to reassure them. If the protein level of gene X is important in your study, and you haven't shown that the level is consistent between conditions or whatever it is that the reviewer is hoping to verify, it seems you have to do something about it.

After that, the editor decides. The paper can be rejected for any reason they see fit; that's their job, after all.

Answer (score 2):

A referee can recommend rejection for a number of random reasons.  The point is that the editor has judged the argument to be reasonable and have merit, whether you yourself judge the argument to be reasonable and have merit.

You can reply to the editor arguing that the argument of the referee are not important, but it seems to me the editor has shown their hand already.  Thus, it would appear that you are out of luck with that journal.

Comment: What about the question tells you what the editor thinks?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist the editor did accept the referee report, else it would not have been communicated to the authors, or at least the editor would have commented to the authors.

Comment: I do not believe that an editor would choose not to send a report to authors.  I think editors would only very rarely criticize a referee.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist we believe differently.   In this case, it is clear the editor choose to give approximately equal weight to both reports and therefore *de facto* endorsed the objections of referee 2. It is always the prerogative of an editor to seek a third opinion if they are confronted with a split decision from two referees, and in this case the editor chose not to do this.  Although not stated explicitly by the OP, the outcome appears to be that acceptance depends on satisfying referee 2, an outcome that any competent editor would recognize.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist an editor would indeed rarely criticize a referee, at least through correspondence with authors or other referees in the process.  Better for the editor to see another referee and provide a third perspective, and overrule referee 2 if a third party agreed with referee 1.  But of course in this case the editor chose NOT to do this.